# Using global to create a singleton object resulting in multiple initialization

Tags: python, debugging, design-patterns

I am facing a problem where the global variable within my module keeps on getting initialized multiple times when `produce()` is called. The module is imported just once but I am still unable to understand why the global variable within the module will become `None`.

Am I taking the right approach?
Looking to make it work in python 2.7 and upwards.

```
producer_instance = None

def produce(message):
    producer = get_producer()
    producer.produce(message)

def get_producer():
    global producer_instance
    if producer_instance is None:        
        producer_instance = Producer()
    return producer_instance
```

Comment: I don't see any way that could be happening unless you have other code that sets `producer_instance`.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times a module is imported because they are cached in `sys.modules` the first time it occurs. I agree with @Barmar that there's nothing in the code in your question that would reset `producer_instance` back to `None` after `get_producer()` is called — no matter how many times it's `import`ed.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I tried reproducing it but I am only seeing in production. Also, I have this happening inside a Django project that is deployed in kubernetes. I am ok to close this if this doesn't help us in coming to a conclusion, but Thank you everyone for taking a look!